# Is there a way to change the player controlled faction's name?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband, mount-and-blade

I was part of Swadian rebels for a while, which didn't work out, and now, I have started my own kingdom, after the Nord king refused to grant me land. But the name of my kingdom is still Swadian Rebels.

Is there any text file to change or other way that I could change the name of my Kingdom to something else?

Answer (score 6):

You can rename your Kingdom while in your Camp. ([Camp wiki page](http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Camp))